# xslt analyze-string alternative in version 1.0

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Could you please help me to convert the below XSLT 2.0 code to XSLT 1.0

```
    <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\s*\w+([-+.'_%]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*\s*">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <a href="mailto:{.}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

What this code is doing is to look in the text for something that looks like an email address, and then to add markup if that is the case. Doing this without regular expressions is pretty well impossible, though you could come up with some kind of approximation (the regular expression itself is probably only an approximation to true email address syntax anyway).

Most XSLT 1.0 engines are likely to offer some way of calling out to external functions to do regular expressions, and that's probably your best option if you really can't use XSLT 2.0. So it depends on which XSLT 1.0 processor you are using.

(But in C# and .net, there are plenty of good XSLT 2.0 processors, so why are you still using 1.0?)